# Python Selenium webdriver timeout exception

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm working on a project to extract some data from a website. In this website there is search form that I should fill it. One of the inputs which is text, shows a suggestion after entering 2 or 3 characters and I should select that option in order to go forward or search button will be activated. The problem is that when I use the following code:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='LocationSuggestionBox']/ul/div/li/div"))).click()
```

I modified the xpath in above code. The actual xpath is as fllow:

```
//*[@id="LocationSuggestionBox""]/ul/div/li/div
```

But I don't know how to add it in my code to not get the syntax error.

The final result with my working code is :

```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='LocationSuggestionBox']/ul/div/li/div"))).click()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Comment: Could you post what the HTML on the page looks like when you are trying to click the suggestion option? This code looks fine but it is hard to tell what is wrong without any context from the page you are testing. From the `TimeoutException`, it looks like the `wait` is timing out because the `EC.element_to_be_clickable` condition is never met.

Comment: The webpage is https://locatr.cloudapps.cisco.com/WWChannels/LOCATR/openBasicSearch.do;jsessionid=8CDF9284D014CFF911CB8E6F81812619            I want to fill the form and search based on that. But When I enter the name of location, suggestion box appears and the mentioned problem occurs.

Comment: Which element you want to click?

Comment: for example type china in location box and then suggestionbox appears behind that. I want to click on that in order have something in my location textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath is returning `NULL` when I run against the page, so the selector is incorrect here.

Based on the page info you provided, here's a correct selector:

`"//li[div/span[text()='" + locationNameHere + "']]"`

So you can change your code to:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[div/span[text()='" + locationNameHere + "']]"))).click()
```

If you just want to click the first location suggestion, you can use this:

`//li[div/span]`

But this XPath will get you a list of ALL visible location suggestions.

Comment: I used copy xpath from google chrome, and because I used chromdriver I thought that my code was correct

Comment: sometimes the selectors from chrome xpath are not always correct. I use an XPath chrome extension to test mine out, which is how I was able to write a new one for you. You can install it if you want https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Induce `WebDriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable()` And following xpath.

```
driver.get('https://locatr.cloudapps.cisco.com/WWChannels/LOCATR/openBasicSearch.do;jsessionid=8CDF9284D014CFF911CB8E6F81812619')
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='searchLocationInput']"))).send_keys('China')
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='ng-scope']//span[text()='CHINA']"))).click()
```

**Browser snapshot:**

[image]

Comment: It needs to know the result of suggestionbox